# How to visually distinguish weechat's active window?

Tags: irc, weechat

I need to have opened several windows at once, but I often type into a wrong one by mistake. How can I visually distinguish the active window, for example by a background color of the input line (or perhaps the whole window)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `weechat.look.color_inactive_window` to `on`, which will dim all windows except the currently active one with the colour defined in `weechat.color.chat_inactive_window`.

Comment: while not as obvious, you can also look for which buffer the cursor is in.